# Jersey java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to make a web-service with Tomcat and Eclipse using jersey library. 
This is my service class:

```
package com.gontuseries.university;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/university")
public class UniversityRestWs {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String getHtmlUniversityInfo(){
        return "<html><body>test</body></html>";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTextUniversityInfo(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

And this is file web.xml

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
 <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
 <param-value>com.gontuseries.university</param-value>
 </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When i test my service i get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
I downloaded jersey from https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Put `jersey-server.jar` in the classpath .

Comment: I did it. But it still doesn't work. 
I've also tried another project with different libraries. I added them into WEB-INF/lib folder, and setted the classpath with eclipse in
Java Build Path-> libraries -> Web app libraries. 
It seems i'm not able to add external libraries in my project.

Answer (score 13):

For me the problem was that the server had no jars in the lib folder.
Make sure it has access to all dependencies in:
project -> properties -> development assembly -> add -> java build path entries.

Answer (score 13):

We need to use ***provide build path to Eclipse***. That must resolve issue.

Make sure it has access to all dependencies in: 
**project -> properties -> development assembly -> add -> java build path entries --> maven dependency**

jersey bundle dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>1.17</version>
<dependency>
```

If you are using maven, best few simple steps will work your application

Comment: I did forgot that, Thanks: project -> properties -> deployment assembly -> add -> java build path entries --> maven dependency (WEB-INF/lib)

Answer (score 7):

Man, I had the same problem. I solve id adding the jersey-servlet-1.18.jar to the WEB-INF/lib.
Then, this folder saw like this:

[image: .]

Remember, add all this jars to yout build-path

Comment: After I add jersey-servlet.jar I get a javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer noclassdeffounderror.. I then added all the jar's (as mentioned above) i get the same expection

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Jersey 2.x?  If so, the `ServletContainer` class has been moved to another package.  This article has some good info on how to change your web.xml when migrating from Jersey 1.7 to 2.x: 
https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2013-06/message/91.

Answer (score 4):

The `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` class is contained in the "jersey-servlet.jar" so you should put it to WEB-INF/lib along with the "jersey-server.jar".

Comment: After I add jersey-servlet.jar I get Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer. I am using Jersey 1.15

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error -"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer", while trying to execute restful jersey web service in tomcat from eclipse.

Following steps helped me to resolve the issue :

- Correct the maven dependency to right version of dependent jars

  ```
       <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
       <version>1.19</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
       <version>1.19</version>
       </dependency>
  ```
- Right click on the eclipse project -> Maven -> Update Project
- Ensure in eclipse properties development assembly is configured correctly.   Right click on project - Properties -> development assembly -> Add -> java build path entries -> maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JERSEY-jaxrs-ri-2.9 version zip, Use the given below in WEB.XML file.

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
   ......
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in an Eclipse project that had previously worked fine, running on Tomcat 7.0.  Eventually I solved it by removing the project from Tomcat and adding it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Above provided solutions are correct but even after making these changes i was getting this error. So what I did was removed all the maven downloaded Jersey jars and update Project again with new maven dependency and that resolved my issue

Answer (score -1):

We get this error because of build path issue and **outdated dependency names.Latest one's start from org.glassfish and not com.sun.After replacing with latest dependencies for 2.0,** You should add "Server Runtime" libraries in Build Path.

"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer"

Please follow below steps to resolve class not found exception.

Right click on project --> Build Path --> Build Path --> Add Library --> Server Runtime --> Apache Tomcat v7.0

Thanks,
Sachin G N